# Asking for a solution on a problem in Numerical linear algebra by Lloyd N. Trefethen, David Bau III

Tags: matrix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CReO8.jpg)

I can not figure out how could the entries of L matrix can not exceed 1, since the symmetric pivoting only involves the diagonal matrix. Consider a matrix where the diagonal entries are very small. How could |l_{ij}|<=1 possible?

Please someone help...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is nothing to do with programming

Comment: Have you considered searching/asking [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?